# Is there something like the conditional operator but for expressions?

Tags: c#

For assignments of a value to a varbiable, I can use the following:

```
className = special ? "Test" : "";
```

But what if I instead want to call a function only if special is true? I have tried

```
special?classNameIsTest() : classNameIsNotTest();
```

But that does not work. Is there something like this? Or should I just keep using

```
if(special) classNameIsTest();
else classNameIsNotTest();
```

Comment: Does `classNameIsTest()` return something or is it `void`?

Comment: It should work if both `classNameIsTest` and `classNameIsNotTest` return the same type.  Neither can return `void`.

Comment: You've not provided enough information. What type is `special`? What are the return values of the two functions? And what does *does not work* mean specifically? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what you're trying to do which includes the necessary variable and function definitions.

Comment: Don't try to do that. An `if...else` is perfect here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If both methods have same signature (same parameters and same return type) you can do this. for example if both methods are void and take no parameters

```
(special ? (Action)Foo : Bar).Invoke();
```

If both methods take an integer but are void

```
(special ? (Action<int>)Foo : Bar).Invoke(20);
```

If both methods take an integer, an string, and return boolean

```
bool result = (special ? (Func<int, string, bool>)Foo : Bar).Invoke(20, "...");
```

---

So you can kind of do this but i don't do that because this is not usual way of programming. it just adds boilerplate code.

Comment: I like your solution for void calls :)

Comment: @ChristianMüller `(special ? (Action)Foo : Bar)();` also works but that doesn't look like c# anymore!

Comment: so you accept my answer, welcome to the wrong side of programming :)

Comment: Thank you :) I like it much

Comment: That is exactly what I was asking for, and you are right, I am not going to use this. But it's nice to know

Answer (score 3):

You can use this phrase

```
var dummy = special ? Test1() : Test2();
```

But both can't be void and must have the same return type.

So... I usually wouldn't use this and stick with "if". You should only use this expression to make the code more maintainable and readable.

In your case... I would assume it will make the code less understandable.

Answer (score 2):

Let me preface this answer by saying I don't actually recommend doing this, but you can play some interesting syntactical tricks with extension methods.

```
public static void Then(this bool x, Action whenTrue, Action whenFalse)
{
   if (x) whenTrue();
   else whenFalse();
}
```

You then use it like `special.Then(Test1, Test2);`